# how to redirect to same page in php after signin ( same as youtube do)?

Tags: php

How to redirect to same page in php after sign in.
Same as the feature of YouTube, it asks us for sign in if we desire to like the videos or comment the videos. And after signing in it will redirect to same page or same video where we were before. how can we do that in php? please anyone help me with the php code.

Comment: You need to attempt this yourself first, we can't provide you with the full code to your solution based on this one paragraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the page that was used to host the login form in a hidden input in that form. Use a `Location` header to send the user back there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `header('location:http://yourdomail.com')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the current URL and pass it to the login form, preferably as a POST variable. Once the user has logged in use the header() function to redirect them back to the URL passed along with the form.

Answer (score 0):

Well what are you looking for is http referer using this you can find out from which page you are being redirected. Save the previous url in session or somewhere else and after sign in just redirect them to that url.

Following is the link for http referer

http://www.julianbez.com/blog/2005/07/14/using-http_referer-in-php/

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `refresh` to set time interval in redirecting like :

```
header('Refresh: thelocation.php', 5);
```